# How can I count the number of results from another count clause?

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and I am trying to work out the following mysql query in MAMP.

> How many departments have more than 5 employees?

```
SELECT DEPid, COUNT(employeeID) AS Employees
FROM dep2emp
GROUP BY DEPid
HAVING Employees > 5;
```

Giving

```
+---------+---------------+
| DEPid   |  Employees
+---------+---------------+
| 1753348 |             7 |
| 1757423 |             6 |
| 1894619 |             7 |
| 1895159 |             7 |
| 1930793 |            11 |
| 1930810 |             8 |
| 2261598 |             7 |
| 2357543 |             6 |
+---------+---------------+`
```

I cannot count the number of results from the other count statement. This is what I've come up with so far and I have tried to use the count clause on the DEPid attribute but it gives me a completely wrong answer of 4141 the answer I am trying to achieve is 8, the number of rows in the result

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Count(employeeID) return the number of rows where the value of employeeID is not null so
Could be you need  just the count of distinct employeeID

```
SELECT DEPid, COUNT(distinct employeeID) AS Employees
FROM dep2emp
GROUP BY DEPid
HAVING  COUNT(distinct employeeID) > 5;
```

count(distinct colname) return the number of distinct value for your colname

Comment: One would hope that an employee is not in the same dept more than once :) But you never know